# Ajax único com outputs diferentes que não funciona sem async

Tags: jquery, ajax

Olá. Eu tenho uma função com uma requisição ajax dentro (essa é a função real):

```
function carregaAjax(caminho,tabela,funcao,dados){
    dados.push({name:"funcao", value:funcao});
    dados.push({name:"tabela", value:tabela});
    var retorno;
    $.ajax({
        url: caminho,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: dados,
        async: false
    })
    .done(function(res) {
        var resposta = JSON.parse(res);

        if($.isArray(resposta)){
            retorno = resposta;
        }
        else if(resposta == 1){
            retorno = resposta;
        }
    })
    .fail(function(res) {
    })
    .always(function() {
    });
    return retorno;
}
```

Tem alguns erros a serem tradados no `.done` de acordo com o que vai ser devolvido, portanto ignorem. O `data:dados` sempre vai ser um array com tudo o que eu preciso, e isso é tratado no servidor de acordo com a entrada.

Esse ajax me atende para tudo, mas ele tem uns problemas, ele precisa ser `async: false` ou então não vai funcionar, por causa daquela variável `retorno`. Ela simplesmente não funciona se não for async.

Esse ajax é a única comunicação com o servidor, ou seja, todas as informações que eu quero buscar ou salvar no BD ou no próprio sistema (é um sistema relativamente grande feito em PHP) são feitas através dela. O `retorno` pode ser true/false, uma string ou mesmo um grid inteiro para montar uma tabela em outra função JS.

O que posso fazer para não depender do async? Ou está tudo errado?

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!

Tente como no exemplo abaixo:

```
var ajaxData = {
     categoria:  'produtos',
     consulta:   'exibirProduto',
     codProduto: $('#produtoFieldCodProduto')
};

var meuAjax = function (fn) {
    $.ajax ({
      type: 'POST',
      data: ajaxData,
      url:  'http://localhost/webService/',
      error: function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      },
      success: functions (jsonData) {
          fn (jsonData);
      }
    });
```

Os dados você consegue recuperar da seguinte forma em qualquer contexto dentro do script:

```
meuAjax (function (json) {
    console.log (json); // resposta
});
```

Sempre faço dessa forma quando quero externar dados de ajax.